# Is it possible to execute and test the application on windowsphone 7.0 and 7.5 launcher in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to execute and test the application on windowsphone 7.0 and 7.5 launcher in visual studio 2010 express.

for windowsphone7.5, programfiles/microsoft sdks/windowsphone/v7.1/tools we have a xap deployment and xde launcher, on the same way v7.0/Tools/ is it possible to get xap deployment and xde launcher for windowsphone 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Both the emulators are available, yes. But your application should target a particular version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would bother to do this? If you upgraded the application to use the 7.1 (Mango) API, it won't run on the 7.0 emulator.

And if you didn't, it'll  have no effect to run it on the 7.1 emulator.

Also, there's no reason to support Windows Phone 7.0, since all phones can be upgraded to Mango (and almost all of them are)